# match extent of two rasters in R

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have two raster:

```
  raster1
  
  class       : SpatRaster 
  dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
  resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
  extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

  raster2
  
  class       : SpatRaster 
  dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
  resolution  : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
  extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84
```

I want to run zonal stastics to calculate sum of smaller raster `raster1` on bigger raster `raster2`:

```
  terra::zonal(raster1, raster2, fun = sum, as.raster=T, filename = 'zonal.tif') 
  Error: [zonal] dimensions and/or extent do not match
```

I wasn't sure why the extent are not matching until I did this

```
  terra::ext(raster1)
  SpatExtent : -180.000001017276, 180.000001017276, -90.0000010172997, 90.0000010172997 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  
  terra::ext(raster2)
  SpatExtent : -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

which shows that `raster1` extent have some imprecision. What are different ways I can fix this?

EDIT: I tried the suggestion in the comment

```
terra::crs(raster2) <- sf::st_crs(4326)$wkt
terra::crs(raster1) <- sf::st_crs(4326)$wkt

terra::ext(raster2)
SpatExtent : -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

terra::ext(raster1)
SpatExtent : -180.000001017276, 180.000001017276, -90.0000010172997, 90.0000010172997 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

But my extent are still not matching

Comment: Have you tried defining a proper CRS on both raster? `terra::crs(raster1) <- sf::st_crs(4326)$wkt`. Not really sure if there is a `terra` helper to extract wkt / proj4 notations from EPSG codes.

Comment: Note that the other raster now has an odd extent after assigning a CRS. But ok, second try: Can they even match considering your resolution of `raster1`? I'm thinking of `360 %% 0.008333333 == 0`.

Comment: Apologies. I corrected the raster names.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is

> Error: [zonal] dimensions and/or extent do not match

In this case, that clearly refers to the difference is dimensions, which are

```
#dimensions  : 21600, 43200, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#dimensions  : 720, 1440, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
```

I do not think the small difference in the extent is relevant at all.

To make the dimensions match you can use `disagg` or `aggregate` with a factor of 30.

If the crs of raster2 is different from that of raster1 you can (in this case, where you clearly have two global lon/lat rasters) fix that with

```
crs(raster2) <- crs(raster1)
```

And for good measure, you could in this case also do

```
ext(raster2) <- ext(raster1)
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth to add this to the documentation then? I would not have expected problems here since - from my point of view - the dimensions do match, they only differ uniformly by a factor of 30 in direction of x and y. So I expected `zonal` to handle this internally. If they have to be of same dimension, I'd consider this as noteworthy in the description. Maybe also add `aggregate` and `disagg` to `@seealso`?

Answer (score 0):

Mismatching extents don't stop `zonal` working, so I think that error message is wrong. Here's two rasters that only differ in their CRS:

```
> library(terra)
terra 1.5.21
> raster1 = rast()
> raster1[]=1:360
> raster2 = rast()
> raster2[]=1:360
> crs(raster1) = ""
> zonal(raster1, raster2)
Error: [zonal] dimensions and/or extent do not match
```

I guess it could be argued that a different CRS means a different extent in the same way that "23" is different to "23 km". But the extent and the dimensions are all the same according to these tests:

```
> ext(raster1) == ext(raster2)
[1] TRUE
> dim(raster1) == dim(raster2)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Rasters with a different extent work fine with `zonal` (once I've set the CRSs to match):

```
> ext(raster2) = c(-180.01, 180.01, -90.01, 90.01)
> crs(raster2) = ""
> z = zonal(raster1, raster2)
>
```

If you do want to change an extent, you can use `ext(r) = ...` as above, but you should try and figure out why extents don't match. Likely its because you have data on points and you may have cells extending out from points...

Comment: Thanks Spacedman for this explanation. I will try to figure out what's happening in my case

Comment: you are right about the error message for mismatching CRSs, and that has been fixed. However, that is likely not the root of the problem (I cannot say for sure, as the information provided in the question is incomplete).